# EF Code First: how to seed tables in a One-To-Many relationship?

Tags: ef-code-first

Here's my model

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }

    public int GenreID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int MovieLength { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(1000)]
    public string MovieSummary { get; set; }

    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class ZimelleShopDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

ScottGu has written a [Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) that shows how to seed a table. I'd like to know how to seed the above example with in case of those 2 tables in One-To-Many relationship.

Thanks for helping

**EDIT**

I did it the other way around, and it worked. The only thing I had to take care of is to instantiate the ICollection.

```
public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }

    //...
}
```

Then I did this

```
protected override void Seed(ZimelleShopDbContext context)
    {
        var genre = new Genre { GenreName = "Foo" };
        var movie = new Movie { Title = "Bar", MovieSummary = "Baz" };

        genre.Movies.Add(movie);
        context.Genres.Add(genre);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

It still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `IEnumerable<Movie> Movies` with `ICollection<Movie> Movies` because `IEnumerable` is not a collection interface.

```
public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

In your initializer

```
protected override void Seed(ZimelleShopDbContext context)
{
     var genre = new Genre { GenreName = "Foo" };
     var movie = new Movies { Title = "Bar", MovieSummary = "Baz", Genre = genre };

     context.Movies.Add(movie);

     context.SaveChanges ();
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I tried to go by genre instead of the movie (see EDIT above). Thank you.